# How to get arrows appear on carousel only on hover

Tags: css, hover, carousel, owl-carousel

For my wordpress theme I'm building I added the owl carousel.  I was able to get the navigation appear how I want.  Arrows on the side of the carousel.

But now my problem is that I want the arrows to only appear when you hover over the carousel.  ( An example is http://www.whowhatwear.com - the squares)

I was able to get the arrows to show when you hover over one spot on the carousel, but I want them to show when you scroll anywhere over the carousel.  Does anyone have a solution?

Here is my css

```css
/* Navigation */
.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
  z-index:100;
  font-size:3rem;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:#000000; 
}

.owl-prev {
  left:-10px;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.owl-next {
  right:-10px;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
  color: #555;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;/*IE7 life-saver */
  font-size: 3rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);/*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top:-32px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div:hover {
  color:#000000;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove all `opacity` properties and use this CSS:

```
.owl-buttons {
  display: none;
}

.owl-carousel:hover .owl-buttons {
  display: block;
}
```

For example: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/GqbWYd

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
      itemsDesktop : [1499,4],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [1199,3],
      itemsTablet : [899,2],
      itemsMobile : [599,1],
      navigation : true,
      navigationText : ['<span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>','<span class="fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x"></i><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i></span>'],
  });
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css');
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.owl-buttons {
  display: none;
}
.owl-carousel:hover .owl-buttons {
  display: block;
}

.owl-item {
  text-align: center;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  background: transparent;
  color: #869791;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/936/c69/?text=1" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/693/9c6/?text=2" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/369/69c/?text=3" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/c33/f66/?text=4" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/099/3cc/?text=5" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300/f93/fc6/?text=6" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user6738171 I've added an example into my answer, Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get really picky and fade them in on hover you can do it with hsla or rgba opacity..

**css**

```
.carousel-buttons {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0); /*hide buttons by default*/
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0); /*hide buttons by default*/
  transition: all 0.2s linear; /*adjust for your fade effect*/
}
.carousel:hover .carousel-buttons {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1); /*show buttons on carousel hover*/
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1); /*show buttons on carousel hover*/
}
.carousel-buttons:hover {
  background-color: hsla(25, 50%, 75%, 1)!important; /*important needed for hover on individual button*/
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1)!important; /*important needed for hover on individual button*/
}
```

be sure to remove the opacity in your current css as mentioned by Gleb.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/92L3m327/1/

---

Another option, let jquery handle the fade effect.

(this example looks a little wonky, i think cuz im using `display: flex` and `display: block` is what jquery unfortunately sets by default)

**css**

```
.carousel-buttons {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 1);
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
}

.carousel-buttons:hover {
  background-color: hsla(25, 50%, 75%, 1);
  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);
}
```

**html**

```
<!-- start them out with display: none; set in inline styles -->
<div class="carousel-buttons carousel-button-left" style="display: none;">l</div>
<div class="carousel-buttons carousel-button-right" style="display: none;">r</div>
```

**jquery**

```
// jquery show will change them to display: block
$('.carousel')
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $('.carousel-buttons').show(200);
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $('.carousel-buttons').hide(200);
  });
// jquery hide will change them to back to display: none
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/92L3m327/2/

Comment: You've got the most appropriate name for 75% of the StackOverflow userbase I've ever seen.

Comment: Ha! I guess my parents were prophetic.

Comment: This isn't a fake name? Did you ever [translate that](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/Hastig%20Zusammenstellen)?

Comment: I'm just kiddin ya, it's my fake first and middle name. Last name's Scheisse. :D

Comment: Pranked by an obvious pranker. Definitely lost my last piece of faith in humanity.